# Using eigen tensor fft

Tags: c++, tensorflow, fft, eigen

I had a look at implementing a CPU fft for tensorflow using the eigen [tensor fft module](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/src/60f8b0f18340337e036b566bc583c77deb52f965/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/TensorFFT.h?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default). Benoit Steiner offered some advice on how to use it [here](https://listengine.tuxfamily.org/lists.tuxfamily.org/eigen/2016/02/msg00071.html).

The eigen fft uses the templated type of the corresponding tensor to perform its computation. Unfortunately, the [inputs](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.h#L581) extracted from the `OpKernelContext` are declared `const` because inputs are immutable. I thus end up with a bunch of compiler errors that const variables cannot be assigned to (because the `TensorFFTOp` reuses the templated typename internally).

What's the best way to get around this problem? Some thoughts:

- use a [`mutable_input`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.h#L614) but that seems like bending the API just to get around a problem
- modify the `TensorFFTOp` with `std::remove_const` such that non-`const` variables are used internally
- explicitly instantiate the `TensorFFTOp` rather than using the template member functions defined in [`TensorBase.h`](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/src/60f8b0f18340337e036b566bc583c77deb52f965/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/Tensor/TensorBase.h?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#TensorBase.h-501)

The last option seems to be the most straightforward but I am struggling with getting all the template arguments right. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of a co worker, we managed to get the desired behaviour by simply casting the `const` input array to a non-`const` one.

```
typename TTypes<T, 2>::Tensor& casted_input = *reinterpret_cast<typename TTypes<T, 2>::Tensor*>(&input);
auto result = casted_input.template fft<Eigen::BothParts, Eigen::FFT_FORWARD>(dims);
```